# Add custom entries to acknowledgments.plist generated by Cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods

Cocoapods generates a plist which can be copied "post_install" to the settings bundle.

I'd love to add some custom entries in for items which need attribution but aren't Cocoapods.

I've looked through the source for https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-acknowledgements but I am not familiar with Ruby and I can't figure out where to start.

```
post_install do | installer |
    require'fileutils'
    FileUtils.cp_r('Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-xxx/Pods-xxx-acknowledgements.plist', 'xxx/Settings.bundle/Acknowledgements.plist', :remove_destination => true)


end
```

I don't need someone to write a whole solution for me, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: If I understand the description correctly, you want to add custom entries in the cocoapods' acknowledgement.plist file before the `post_install` step to settings bundle kicks off. Am I correct in understanding this? Also, what's the code fragment that you have posted here?

Comment: hi @erosenin thanks for the clarification. I'd like to add extra entries to the file that gets copied to the settings bundle, when that happens isn't too important. The other code was a workaround for a bug in cocoa pods from a while back, I've removed it now.

Comment: Why do you need to intervene in that file specifically? Have you tried to manually create another acknowledgement file and just merge them both in runtime, or post install?

Comment: @LiorPollak merging with another file would be perfect. would I do this with the FileUtils class in the Podfile? As far as I can tell modifying the settings bundle at runtime isn't an option?

Answer (score 2):

As my not complete answer got deleted, here now the full working version:

Based on this python script: https://gist.github.com/wagyu298/cb11f5d6eabd9acc7425cc106fc03fd2

We came up with a solution in our project:

```rb
def add_license_manually
  require 'cfpropertylist'
  additional_license = {
    "FooterText" => "Copyright (c) 2020, Example Dev All rights reserved.

    Redistribution......",
    "License" => "MIT",
    "Title" => "Library",
    "Type" => "PSGroupSpecifier"
  }
  ack_plist_name = 'Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-xxx/Pods-xxx-acknowledgements.plist'
  # read plist
  plist = CFPropertyList::List.new(:file => ack_plist_name)
  # convert to native data
  data = CFPropertyList.native_types(plist.value)
  # append the license
  data["PreferenceSpecifiers"].insert(-1, additional_license)
  # convert back
  plist.value = CFPropertyList.guess(data)
  # write plist to file
  plist.save(ack_plist_name, CFPropertyList::List::FORMAT_XML)
end
```

And in your post_install, you add  add_license_manually() before the

```
FileUtis.cp_r(...)
```

line